# problem applying augmentation on train data

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification, data-augmentation

I have image dataset of 102 images belong to 3 classes. I have stored the image_path, label, image (loaded using io so its np.array) in a dataframe. Split to train test val, then I'm trying to apply data augmentation to add it to the train data to increase it using the following :

```py
#apply augmentation
target_size = (224, 224)

# Create lists to store augmented images and labels
augmented_path = []
augmented_images = []
augmented_labels = []

for image_path, label in zip(train_data['image_path'], train_data['label']):
    img = load_img(image_path, target_size=target_size)
    img_array = img_to_array(img) / 255.0  # Normalize the image
    img_array = img_array.reshape((1,)+img_array.shape)  # Add batch dimension
    label = np.array([label]).reshape(1, -1)  # Reshape label as needed

    # Generate augmented images and labels
    for _ in range(30):  # Define the number of augmentations per image
        augmented_image = train_datagen.flow(img_array, batch_size=1)
        augmented_label = label
        
        augmented_path.append(image_path)
        augmented_images.append(augmented_image[0])
        augmented_labels.append(augmented_label)
```

augmented_labels list output looks like this:

```
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]]),
 array([[1]])
```

...and more 2130 row classes that ranges between [0 - 2]

The problem is when I apply augmentation it reshapes the labels and image column arrays to a a bigger shape .. I want it to stay the same as the original train data so I can concat them and they have the same shape

[column shapes before augmentation original train data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F6aX.png)

[column shapes after applying augmentation and increased the original train data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CUKz.png)

Also, what else can I do to prepare this data for a CNN classification model.